# Initializing any object results in skipping a part of a code

Tags: java, spring, memory, sax

I have a `Spring MVC` application and in my `HomeController` I have code for parsing XML:

```
 SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      // ...
      // load data
      // ....
      // till here everything usually works fine

                SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
                SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();
                saxParser.parse(is, handler);
               }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return "homeView";
        }
```

The problem is that when I try to create new instance of any object within `SaxHandler` that `extends DefaultHandler`, my app then randomly skips parts of the program and displays the View. When I try to create instance of some other Object, it usually "crashes" in another place - i.e. in `HomeController`.  No stack trace is printed, breakpoints in catch blocks won't help and I'm really confused with this. The version of SDK is `1.8` and AS is `Tomcat 8`. Any idea what could cause it and how to fix it?

Comment: I notice you're not catching RuntimeException...  might be worth a try

Comment: Good point. I already left from work, but I'll definitely give it a try tomorrow. I've never experienced anything like this and it's just blowing my mind :-/

Comment: no result anyway :-/

Comment: It's probably not java-related. I was using IntelliJ Idea 14 Ultimate. Nevertheless today I tried to run the same code in Eclipse Luno, with the same SDK, Java version and AS and it works without problem... So it will be probably some IDE-specific problem :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by IDE - `IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 14.0.3`. In Eclipse Luna it worked without problem. I realized that this problem started to occur, after I installed some plugins to IDE. Deleting IDE with all plugins and reinstallation helped. Nevertheless I still didn't install plugins to it, so I can't say for 100% sure, if this is, what caused the problem. But I sometimes noticed a message in terminal that Mongo plugin could cause memory leaks, so this is my hot candidate.